# Android Google Maps API map toolbar doesnt appear 7.5.71

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

On a few different devices, all running Google Play services v7.5.71, the map toolbar that used to slide out doesn't anymore.

From emulator (running whatever play services comes installed on the Google APIs for API 22, it's < 7.x.x):

[image]

From nexus 5 (running 7.5.71):

[image]

This might not be the right forum for this, just trying to get a note out there for other people who run into this issue.

Does anyone know of a way around this? It behaves this way whether you explicitly enable it via `getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);` or let it default (enabled) and don't make that call at all (because it has nothing to do with my code, it's whatever version of play services the device has installed)

**EDIT**

Here's the bug report if you wanna star it: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8115

Comment: the funny thing is I reported a bug with the toolbar in 7.3 where it would always show no matter what in LiteMode. I wonder if they fixed that which caused another bug. EDIT: Ha that does look like its the case as it is now fixed for litemode. I would file a bug report

Comment: what about trying to enable the toolbar when clicking on the marker?

Comment: ha. WELL THANKS FOR BREAKING IT. jk. ill give that other suggestion a shot

Comment: yeah, doesnt work. good suggestion though

Comment: issue reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826486

Answer (score 0):

With further testing, and some reports from users, we found that doing something like this on the fragment the map was in (essentially adjusting the map padding over and over), was causing performance issues, and also issues with the map toolbar.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        adjustMapPadding();
    }
});
```

This WAS working fine, but some update to the google library caused it to have issues because there are now issues with all previous versions of the app.

This fixed both our performance issues, and the map toolbar now works again. So check calls to `map.setPadding`